# DELETE webserice call with Parameter Android

Tags: android, web-services

i have to delete data from List using id but i don't know how to make delete call.
i have to use HttpDelete or something else?

i have check my delete  service on hurl.it.
it works fine but from device i m not able to call delete service..

```
             HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpDelete httpdelete = new HttpDelete(url);
            hp.setParameter("X-API-KEY","sdgdnjtn@#GBTGH");
            hp.setParameter("i_id","10");
            httpdelete.setParams(hp);

             HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpdelete);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya you r doing right. just have a look of it.

```
public static String yourMethod(String url) {

  String result = "";
  try {
   int TIMEOUT_MILLISEC = 100000; // = 10 seconds
   HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
   HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams,TIMEOUT_MILLISEC);
   HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, TIMEOUT_MILLISEC);
   HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
   HttpDelete httpDelete=new HttpDelete(url);
   HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpDelete);
   InputStream is = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
   BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
     is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   String line = null;
   while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(line + "\n");
   }
   is.close();
   result = sb.toString();
  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
   return null;
  }
  return result;
 }
```